# Вызов функции в директиве ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Только начал разбираться с angularjs и столкнулся с проблемой на ровном месте.
Хочу сделать так, чтобы директива ng-click по клику вызывала функцию.  Нашел пример. Написал полностью аналогично, но не работает.
Почему, не могу понять.
Код:

```
<body ng-app="hello">


<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-show="!show" />
<input type="button" value="Поздороваться" ng-click="action;" ng-show="!show" />

<greetings ng-show="show">

</greetings>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

    angular.module('hello', []);
    angular.module('hello').
        directive('greetings', 
        function()
        {
          var obj= 
            {
                scope: true, 
                show: false,
                restrict: 'AE',

               template: '<h1>HELLO {{name}} </h1>',  

                link: function(scope) 
                {
                    scope.action = function()
                    {
                           scope.show = !scope.show;
                           alert('hgkgkhg');
                    };
                }
        };
          return obj;
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете вызывать функцию директивы вне шаблона директивы. Вам нужно переместить шаблон с `ng-click` внутрь директивы.

```
<body ng-app="hello">

<greetings ng-show="show">

</greetings>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

    angular.module('hello', []);
    angular.module('hello').
        directive('greetings', 
        function()
        {
          var obj= 
            {
                scope: true, 
                show: false,
                restrict: 'AE',

               template: '<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-show="!show" />' +
               '<input type="button" value="Поздороваться" ng-click="action;" ng-show="!show" />' +
                  '<h1>HELLO {{name}} </h1>',  

                link: function(scope) 
                {
                    scope.action = function()
                    {
                           scope.show = !scope.show;
                           alert('hgkgkhg');
                    };
                }
        };
          return obj;
      });
</script>
```

Или, вероятно, вам достаточно обычного контроллера.

Comment: не совсем понял ответ:  input в котором я пытаюсь должен вызвать ng-click должен находиться внутри <greetings> или внутри js свойства template?   И почему тогда работает строка в которой я вместо вызова функции, помещаю ее тело  непосредственно в ng-click, находящийся вне директивы.   Извините, если вопрос глупый, я только начал разбираться в ангуляре. Про контроллер - понял, спасибо.

Comment: Уточняю: такой инпут отрабатывает нормально на том же месте где был в моем коде:  <input type="button" value="Поздороваться" ng-click="show=!show"  ng-show="!show"/>

Comment: ng-click вызывается всегда, дело в том что вне директивы функция не определена и ничего не произойдет. В последнем комментарии вы не вызываете функции, поэтому все работает. input должен быть внутри template. Также можно и внутри тега, но тогда нужно использовать transclude.